# How do I send this email in Python, opening files and stuff?

Tags: python, html, django, email, file

```
msg = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, [to_email])
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

This is how I send an email in Django.

But what if I want to open a text file and take into account all its line breaks and tabs. I want to take the body of the text file (with line breaks \n) and email it as text of the "body".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a text file, just send it as text.  If you send it as "HTML", the whitespace won't be significant.

Comment: Will it preserve the line breaks?

Comment: Yes, assuming all the programs are standards-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

In Django itself, it uses render_to_string("", {}) from django.template.loader. The advantage of it is that you can use contexts.